# Leaf nodes from Preorder of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Given a Preorder traversal of a Binary Search Tree. The task is to print leaf nodes of the Binary Search Tree from the given preorder.

Example:

Input : 67 34 12 45 38 60 80 78 79 95 100

Output: 12 38 60 79 100

Following is the recursive solution I came up with but not getting the correct output

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int preorder[MAX], n;

void leaf(int low,int high)         // prints leaf nodes from preorder
{
    if(high <= low)                 // base condition: print the leaf and return
    {
        printf("%d ", preorder[low]);
        return;
    }
   int root = preorder[low];                        //stores the value  of root node;
   int left =root > preorder[low+1]? low+1: low ;   // stores the index of left node, if left subtree ie empty sets left = low
   int right = low;                                 //stores the index of right node. Initialized to low

   for(int i = low; i<=high; i++)                   //finds the right node. i.e. first node larger than root(between low and high)
   {
       if(root < preorder[i]);
       {
           right = i;                               // stores the index of right node
           break;
       }       
   }
    
    if(left != low)                 //if left = low, then left subtree is empty
        leaf(left, right-1);        //recurse on the left subtree
    if(right != low)                //if right = low, then right subtree is empty
        leaf(right,high);           //recurse on the right subtree

}

int main()
{  
    printf("Enter size of input: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter input:");

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&preorder[i]);
    }  

    leaf(0,n-1);
}
```

Comment: For some reason my compiler throws a warning that says the `i++` will never get executed in the statement:  `for(int i = low; i<=high; i++) `.

Comment: You've got a simple typo: `if(root < preorder[i]);` has an excess semicolon: The `if` body is empty and the following code block will be executed unconditionally.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, why not? It was just a typo that does not really warrant a full answer.

Comment: (Okay, I'll eat my words. Accept rykker's answer instead.)

Comment: Yes, I thought you were the OP. I'm obviously better with semicolons than with names. `:(`.

Comment: You can leave your answer there, @rykker. I thought it was the OP asking me to delete the answer. At that time, there wasn't an answer yet and I thought it wasn't worth waiting for one. Hm, this has turned into a social problem rather than a technical one now and I'm bad at those ...

Comment: @MOehm You are right. Forgot that excess semicolon there. Thanks for pointing that out. The code is working fine now.

Comment: @MOehm  - LOL,  Yes, the comments are a mix of good observations and meandering thoughts.  In any case, FWIW,  I have added my post back in...

Answer (score 1):

Typo is here:

```
 for(int i = low; i<=high; i++) //finds the right node. ...
   {
       if(root < preorder[i]);//<-----  
                             ^
       ...
```

Causing the following lines to be executed regarless:

```
   right = i;                               // stores the index of right node
   break;
```